# Silverstripe Scripts not all loading in the backend braking upload field

Tags: upload, silverstripe

I have just updated a live site from changes made to a local site. The upload field on the Gallery Page is not working. Not allowing images to be uploaded, and not allowing the browse "from files" window to load any content. I checked all the files are there and it seems fine.. I'm tempted to reinstall but wondered if anyone new what the error means I'm getting and how to fix it incase this happens again etc. I can upload and browse on other pages and the Files section.

The error message from the console after choosing a file clicking upload (it allow me to browse from my computer) is:

```
[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'func({files:files,formatFileSize:this._formatFileSize,options:this.options})')
_renderTemplate (undefined, line 96)
(anonymous function) (lib.js, line 660)
_renderUpload
(anonymous function) (lib.js, line 660)
add
_trigger (lib.js, line 680)
(anonymous function)
each (lib.js, line 37)
_onAdd
(anonymous function) (lib.js, line 660)
_onAdd
(anonymous function) (lib.js, line 660)
_onChange
(anonymous function) (lib.js, line 660)
dispatch (lib.js, line 207)
eventHandle (lib.js, line 174)
```

I also get this warning:

```
[Warning] Uncaught exception  (lib.js, line 1629)
Error
in on match on <div id=​"Images" class=​"field galleryupload ss-upload ss-uploadfield nolabel"​…​       </div>
```

Comment: From those errors I do not know what is wrong. All I can suggest is calling ?flush=all and running a /dev/build/?flush=all and seeing if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Could be a browser cache issue? Was it working on your local site?